# Wordpress Blog Overview - Requested Page No Longer Available

Tags: wordpress, web, blogs

I was wondering could someone please help. I am working on a WordPress website. I have added blog posts and everything was going fine until unexpectedly I start getting the following message. (Side point: If you look at the message, available is actually spelled incorrectly also - AVAIBLE)

[image]

Now I have 11 blog posts, separated on the blog overview into 4 per page. So 1st page has 4 posts, 2nd page has 4 posts and 3rd page has 3 blog posts. When I set one of the posts as a draft, I should see 2 on the last (i.e. 3rd) page, but instead I see the 404 error page, even though there should be 2 posts on that page. When I publish the drafted post, everything works fine and I see the expected 3 posts on the last page.

Each of the posts themselves are fine, as I have tested clicking on each one and it brings me to their designated page as expected. But it's just in the main overview of the blogs that I'm having the issue.

This is a major issue as I now cannot add blog posts without this happening at certain time. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this can be a non-resolvable quirk in WordPress outside of changing theme/deactivating plugins and the like. It's too hard to debug here since it most likely is not a "code" issue per-se.

Comment: @Aibrean I had installed "WordPress SEO by Yoast" last, I think it may have been something to do with that. Do you know how I would approach trying to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the 404 page of the theme has text is both grammatically incorrect and contains a spelling error, the theme you are working with has, to put it nicely, issues, primarily with pagination and post queries. *(I'd much rather say "the theme is junk).*

Use deductive logic to rule out the theme and plugin(s). Switch to the default WordPress twentyfifteen theme and see if the blog pagination is correct. Deactivate Yoast and see if pagination works.

If the theme is broken, or if Yoast breaks the theme, find a better theme; a good place to look is https://wordpress.org/themes/ All themes in the WordPress directory have been checked out and there are dedicated support forums for each.

Besides that, this is really isn't a programming question. You need to show specific code that is causing the problem, like the page queries themselves. You're better off in the theme and plugin support forums and at https://wordpress.org/support/

Comment: Hi @markratledge, thank you for your comments. 

I suppose I'm so far through with the theme that I have chosen, and my site is going live tomorrow so unfortunately in my present situation I will most likely have to persevere for the moment. 

I have only got this error last night as everything was working fine up until then. I appreciate your direction in terms of where to pick themes from in the future, and I will be sure to check these out for my upcoming sites.

I have already placed on the support page, I was just hoping someone here may have had the same issues and got them resolved :-)